# How do I make something like Minecraft's crafting table

Tags: java, gui, minecraft-modding

I'm making a mod for version 1.16. I want to make a crafting table with 3x3 grid which is automated. I need it to implement and read other mod recipes and minecraft recipes.
I need to know how I to read other recipes and check if the recipe matches.

For example:

```
{

"type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",

"pattern": [
"eee",  
"eee",  
"eee"
]

key {  
"e": "minecraft:diamond"  
},

"result": "minecraft:diamond_block"

}
```

I need it to see if the recipe matches and if it does it will craft.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A mod that does this already exists. Can't remember but it might be in carpet mod? Might be a good place to start.